# Why do I need to clear the router cache after changing route to take effect

Tags: laravel, caching, router

Why do I need to clear the router cache after changing route to take effect. In a tutorial, a tutor was changing the route and it was taking effect without clearing the cache.

Comment: You need to clear the cache if you have run `php artisan route:cache`, else there is no need...

Comment: You don’t need to cache in local developmet in any way. Run php artisan cache:clear and dont use caching in future - only, maybe, for cache test before deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should clear all cache at once first using

> php artisan optimize:clear