# Laravel always have to run php artisan cache:clear & php artisan route:cache after editing route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-artisan

hi guys i have a problem with my device, every time I try to change or add new route I have to run these command int the terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

to make it work otherwise it will still show error. are there any ways that I can do to not always run those command? thankyou

Comment: Works fine on my end without needing to do this all the time.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear`  you don't really need a cache for local testing so you could be happy with `php artisan cache:clear` and then never cache them

Comment: do you rung your app with under Docker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522027/why-do-i-need-to-clear-the-router-cache-after-changing-route-to-take-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond clearing just route out you should also look at clearing all performance optimisations made as well. This include cached bootstrap files such as  events, views ,  cache , route, config , compiled ...

Run the command in your terminal to clear all at once

`php artisan optimize:clear`